# How to extract the Json values in jmeter using regular expression extractor?

Tags: json, regex, web-services, jmeter, ui-automation

```
{  
  "response":{  
    "statusCode":"00",
    "status":"success",
            "responseData":{  
                     "status":1,
                     "themeID":27,
                     "themeName":"ThemeName25",
                     "templateId":22
                           }
             }
}
```

Here i need to retrieve the value of `templateId`, `themeName` using regular expression extractor only not by jmeter plugins like json path extractor. Can anyone having for this solution??

Answer (score 0):

Use the regexen

```
/"themeName":"([^"]+)"/
/"templateId":([0-9]+)/
```

to capture the result.

This goes by the usual caveat that it is **strongly discouraged to use regex patterns as parser substitutes**

One assumption is that values for `templateId` are structly numeric.

Answer (score 0):

To Capture templateId: `templateId":(\d+)`
To Capture themeName: `themeName":"(.+?)"`

The special characters above are:
( and ) - these enclose the portion of the match string to be returned
. - match any character
+ - one or more times
? - stop when first match succeeds
\d - for any digit